# Webpack not seeing file changes in docker alpine

Tags: docker, webpack, alpine-linux

I'm trying to port my already-working webpack app to a docker setup for easier development env setup. I've used a following Dockerfile for this:

```
FROM scardon/ruby-node-alpine
MAINTAINER mbajur@gmail.com

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base python

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /box
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 4567
```

And my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  app: &app_base
    build:
      context: .
    command: webpack --watch -d --color
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - box:/box
    ports:
      - "4567:4567"

volumes:
  box:
```

And i'm running my webpack setup with

```
$ docker-compose up
```

However, for some reason, webpack can't see changes made to my files. Also, after some googling, i've tried using `--watch-poll` instead but it then exits immediately after first build instead watching as a deamon.

What can i do to make it work in docker-alpine ? I have a feeling i'm missing something simple in here.

ps. my project is mostly based on this: https://github.com/grassdog/middleman-webpack

ps2. i'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with webpack config cause it works perfectly fine when used outside of docker

ps3. i've also played with setting up `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` to `524288` but it didn't changed much

Comment: Once you build a dockerfile the contents are finalized and the changes your make in host are not impacting the container. This will only work when your run the container with a volume mount. `docker run -v $PWD:/app <image> ...`

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes you're totally right, i forgot to include my docker-compose. Quesiton body updated

Comment: Which OS are you running the compose on?

Comment: it's OSX / macOS

Comment: I don't think notifications currently work on mac. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/, https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/ and https://medium.freecodecamp.org/speed-up-file-access-in-docker-for-mac-fbeee65d0ee7